# connect to remote host containers database

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy

I have a postgress inside a container in my cloud vm
vm public ipv4 :18.170.23.238
container_name: postgres-db
ports:
- 5432:5432

From my vm I can connect to the database with the code below:
engine = create_engine(
'postgresql+psycopg2:'
'//postgres:'
'docker'
'@postgres-db:5432/'
'postgres')
con = engine.connect()

I want to connect with python in order to query the database from my desktop.

engine = create_engine(
'postgresql+psycopg2:'
'//postgres:'
'docker'
'18.170.23.238:80@postgres-db:5432/'
'postgres')
con = engine.connect()

i have tried changing host at the configuration URLs with various ways like the one above.

what should i change at the code in order to connect the engine with the database